# How do I fix the error? Typescript: Type 'ErrorRequestHandler' is not assignable to type 'IMiddleware'

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

In the following code, I got an error with type reassignment:

```js
export default class AbstractController extends Middleware {

    get middleware(): Express.RequestHandler | Express.ErrorRequestHandler { // (6,22)
        //...
    }

}
```

Error text:

```
src/controller/AbstractController.ts(6,22): error TS2415: Class 'AbstractController' incorrectly extends base class 'Middleware'.
  Types of property 'middleware' are incompatible.
    Type 'ErrorRequestHandler | RequestHandler' is not assignable to type 'IMiddleware'.
      Type 'ErrorRequestHandler' is not assignable to type 'IMiddleware'.
```

Declare RequestHandler and ErrorRequestHandler interfaces:

```js
interface RequestHandler {
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
}

interface ErrorRequestHandler {
    (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
}
```

Declare Middleware class:

```js
export interface IMiddleware {
    (req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse): void;
}

export default class Middleware {

    get middleware(): IMiddleware {
        throw new Error('Не определен middleware.');
    }

}
```

I need to understand not how to fix it, but what is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

The `Middleware` class expects a `IMiddleware` as return type of `middleware()`.

Your interfaces should extend IMiddleware !

```
interface RequestHandler extends IMiddleware {
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
}

interface ErrorRequestHandler extends IMiddleware {
    (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): any;
}
```

However, `ErrorRequestHandler`'s signature does not match `IMiddleware`

Maybe you should create a second interface to represent it.